# Heatmap with Paired Data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, charts, data-visualization, heatmap

I am trying to make a heatmap in Python. I have a dataframe I made that looks like the following.

```
custom_vals = [[.0, .0], [0,5], [0,10], [0,15], [0,20], [0,25],
               [5,0], [5,5], [5,10], [5,15], [5,20], [5,25],
               [10,0], [10,5], [10,10], [10,15], [10,20], [10,25],
               [15,0], [15,5], [15,10], [15,15], [15,20], [15,25],
               [20,0], [20,5], [20,10], [20,15], [20,20], [20,25], 
               [25,0], [25,5], [25,10], [25,15], [25,20], [25,25]] # ordered pairs (G, H)
custom_predict = (np.around(model.predict(custom_vals), decimals=2))
predicted_vals = pd.DataFrame(data=custom_predict, index = ['0, 0', '0, 5','0, 10', '0, 15', '0, 20', '0, 25',
                                                            '5, 0', '5, 5','5, 10', '5, 15', '5, 20', '5, 25',
                                                            '10, 0', '10, 5','10, 10', '10, 15', '10, 20', '10, 25',
                                                            '15, 0', '15, 5','15, 10', '15, 15', '15, 20', '15, 25',
                                                            '20, 0', '20, 5','20, 10', '20, 15', '20, 20', '20, 25',
                                                            '25, 0', '25, 5','25, 10', '25, 15', '25, 20', '25, 25',], columns=[precip_levels])
predicted_vals
```

[image]

In the image, the y-axis contains ordered pairs (`G`, `H`). The probabilities represent the probability of the x-value given the pair of y-values. For example, the probability of x = 0 given g and h = 0 is 0.87 in the table above.

I want to be able to turn this into a heatmap with a color bar for the probabilities. My goal is to separate the ordered pairs (designated as `G` and `H`--see the comment in the code above) such that `G` is on the x-axis and `H` is on the y-axis. I only want to worry about one x-value at a time. For example, I want to make something like the following into a heat map.

[image]

How could I do something like this in Python? I am open to any library.

Comment: `maptlotlib` has `hist2d` ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html)) and `plotly` has `heatmap` ([docs](https://plotly.com/python/2D-Histogram/))

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about how you get from `predicted_vals` to the heatmap data? Does the output from `predicted_vals` correspond to the image above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Seaborn` is an awesome library for data visualization and it's a great friend of `pandas` as well. I highly recommend you reading their documentation one day.

For your problem, there is a quite simple solution. Since `custom_predict` is obtained by a particular function of yours, I've used some random data just as an example.

As you have multiple values for `x` in your original dataframe `predicted_vals`, we may want to filter that based on the desired values of `x` (in your case, 0)

```
desired_val = 5
desired_df = pd.DataFrame()

desired_df[desired_val] = predicted_vals[desired_val]
desired_df[['x', 'y']] = custom_vals
```

Also, we create two columns `x` and `y`, which will be the coordinates provided by `custom_vals`. This will look like this:

```
         0    x     y
0,0   0.84  0.0   0.0
0,5   0.06  0.0   5.0
0,10  0.95  0.0  10.0
0,15  0.70  0.0  15.0
0,20  0.19  0.0  20.0
```

Nextm we need this to look like a real heatmap, given by a DataFrame where the `index`  correspond to the `y` values, and the `columuns`, to the `x` values. This is achieved by using `pivot_table`

```
my_heatmap = desired_df.pivot_table(index='x', columns='y', values=desired_val)
```

Which gives us a dataframe like this:

```
x     0.0   5.0   10.0  15.0  20.0  25.0
y                                       
0.0   0.84  0.73  0.37  0.75  0.55  0.67
5.0   0.06  0.58  0.69  0.86  0.76  0.54
10.0  0.95  0.02  0.59  0.30  0.79  0.36
15.0  0.70  0.10  0.19  0.92  0.04  0.24
20.0  0.19  0.77  0.74  0.12  0.14  0.87
25.0  0.48  0.34  0.99  0.80  0.56  0.43
```

And finally, we can plot the heatmap. We need `seaborn` and `matplotlib.pyplot` for visualization.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.heatmap(my_heatmap, cmap='plasma')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can choose other colormaps by changing the keyword argument `cmap` to one of the many matplotlib colormap names (you can check them [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html)).

Tell us if you have any further issues!

Comment: I get `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` at this line `desired_df[desired_val] = predicted_vals[desired_val]` Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: How do you create the variable `precip_levels`? I've created the dataframe using my own data, probably your data is quite different

Comment: Here is how I created it: `precip_levels = np.sort(pd.unique(df['Categorical_Y_Variable']))
print(precip_levels) #outputs [0. 5. 10. 15. 20. 25.]` - thank you!

Comment: Oh, I think I get what's the problem. When creating your dataframe try changing the keyword argument from `columns=[precip_levels]` to `columns=precip_levels` (without square brackets).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `seaborn`:

```
import numpy as np 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create dummy data
data = np.array(np.random.rand(5, 5))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_figheight(7)
fig.set_figwidth(7)

sns.heatmap(data, annot = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]